# VBScript ObjExec Never Getting A New Status Code

Tags: vbscript

I'm starting on a simple VBscript to automate some of the daily tasks I need done on my computer. It's not going to be complicated-- simply execute a few programs and when they're all done report any error codes. But I'm quite new with VBScript so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
Dim oShell, oExec
Set oShell = CreateObject(WScript.Shell)

Set oExec = oShell.Exec("cmd.exe /C cd path/to/file & runScript")

While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep(250)
Loop

WScript.Echo "Done"
```

The thing is, it hangs forever. It never gets out of the while loop. It seems to work fine if I use oShell.Run, but I need to guarantee every script I'm executing (eventually there will be five, but I'm starting with getting it to work with 1) is complete before reporting. But I don't want them to run one after the other. Running them parallel is perfectly fine and will be much faster.

Bizarrely, it appears that if I use the while loop to print out the script output it works just fine:

```
...
Do
     str = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
     WScript.Echo str
Loop While Not oExec.StdOut.atEndOfStream
...
```

So I'm not sure what the problem is with the Exec command or what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone has a suggestion I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who finds this answer and is as dumbfounded as I was, there were two things I needed to do:

First, some of the StdIn of the oExecs for my scripts were waiting for input. Use `oExec.StdIn.close()` to prevent this. Finally, some of my scripts were acting bizarre when the text had nowhere do to. Direct the output of the scripts with `> nil`. These saved my sanity.